# Svelte: doesn't work inline css animation

Tags: css, animation, svelte, svelte-3

Doesn't work inline css animation like this:

```
<h1 class="test" style="animation: bg 2s linear infinite">Hello {name}!</h1>

<style>
.test { 
    background: yellow;
}

@keyframes bg {
    from {
      background: red;
    }
    to {
      background: green;
    }
  }
</style>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/e32b72cb98cb4b78a47b1bcb1ecab9e9?version=3.53.1

But if delete style attribute

```
<h1 class="test">Hello {name}!</h1>
```

and add

```
.test 
    background: yellow;
    animation: bg 2s linear infinite;
}
```

It works!
But I want to add animation as inline style.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the inline style? `animation` is a shorthand property. If you need variance in e.g. just the speed, you could define everything except `animation-duration` in the `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything within a component style is scoped to the component by default and the inline style apparently is not recognized as referring to the defined `@keyframes`.

Regular selectors can be made global using `:global()` around the selector but for `@keyframes` you would have to prefix the name with `-global-` (which is removed again on compilation).

```css
@keyframes -global-bg { ... }
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c03f851482c749faa32f862b1b9f94b6?version=3.53.1)

Note that this really is defined as global then and any other component that defines global keyframes with the name `bg` will cause interference.

Comment: That's so whack lol but just confirming this does work in the latest version of svelte circa Nov 2023